# Why couldn't the trio Disapparate again after escaping from the Lovegoods' house?

Tags: harry-potter

In the movie Luna's father told the Death Eaters about Harry's whereabouts and when they arrived the trio quickly Disapparated into the Forest. But after arriving there, there are some hunters already waiting for them.

**Why didn't they just Disapparate again instead of running?**

EDIT: [I uploaded the clip from the movie](http://youtu.be/00P_iL3ekGg)

Comment: As I recall, the last time they tried that it ended kind of poorly.

Comment: That was NOT AT ALL how it happened in the book. In the book they escaped into the forest, had a big discussion about Hallows, listened to radio, etc... But yes, there's no answer in the book either over why they didn't just disapparate when Harry said "Voldemort" and triggered Taboo

Comment: @DVK - it's not explicitly said why they didn't disapparate but I give some reasons for it in an answer below.  Basically I don't think they were prepared to disapparate - it all happened too quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Only a wild guess: there are spells that prevent apparition (for instace when they return to Hogsmeade in HP7(2)). Maybe it is part of standard procedure to put those up when about to make arrests, just like Harry/Hermione putting up a bunch of protective charms when arriving somewhere. Still, if this is case books and movie forgot to tell us about that.

Answer (score 2):

They apparated into a field but the hunters weren't already there waiting for them - your memory seems to be mistaking you.  They actually set up camp and were talking for quite some time.  It wasn't until Harry said "Voldemort" that the bad guys showed up.

> "Come out of there with your hands up!" came a rasping voice through
>   the darkness.  "We know you're in there! You've got half a dozen wands
>   pointing at you and we don't care who we curse!"

So after Harry said Voldemort (the name being Taboo at this point) the 'hunters' show up and have the place surrounded.  Hermione has time to perform a spell to make Harry not so recognizable but there probably wasn't time for them to form a quick plan and apparate away from there in a group.  Ron and Harry didn't have their wands ready either so they really couldn't do much at the time.

Comment: Sorry, -1. Side-along apparating was an option since Hermione was ready. This theory doesn't explain the conundrum to me.

Comment: @DVK - I disagree.  They weren't ready and they're not what I would call experts in apparating.  They didn't have time to formulate a plan.  Hermione just trying to grab them and let them know what they were going to do and then doing a double side-along apparation BEFORE they would be hit with spells (and who knows which spells they would use - probably not just something to restrain them - it could be something worse) doesn't seem entirely feasible to me.  Would it have been possible? Maybe - but I have no problem believing that it was just too much in too little time to ask for.

Comment: Yes, Ron is bad at appating and Harry doesn't like it. But we have no information indicating side along apparition is harder than apparating alone. Also, apprating doesn't take a long time of premeditation or anything. They really just could have abandoned the place.

Comment: @user1129682 They could have attempted to.  But like I said I don't think they were prepared.  You can idealize them as much as you want but if you toss somebody in a situation like that they might not take the ideal course of action immediately.  I think I proposed a reasonable reason for why they didn't disapparate.  You don't have to agree with me but I think it's a reasonable explanation for why they didn't just leave immediately via apparation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was more of a shock when Harry said the name and they felt all their protective spells break they didn't really have time to apparate properly which takes concentration and focus to do if you don't focus your entire mind on apparating you increase your chances of splinching yourself so they could of hurriedly apparated and risked leaving a leg or an arm behind or even half their body as has happened to witches and wizards before not to mention they were probably hesitant about doing it because the last time the attempted it as an escape attempt not only did the show a death eater the secret of Sirius blacks house they also splinched Ron on the vanish to escape after giving away the secret